# scraping the header data of a data table when SelectorGadget doesn't apply? (scraping fundamentals)

Tags: r, rvest

Theses two pages have the same data tables (one serves as backup if another is down).  I'm able to get the column data from each of the page's tables from `library(XML)`'s `readHTMLTable()` but unable to get the header of the table. All that I need header wise is the date-year timestamp (currently, `August 2019`), to assign to the data.  In the little scraping I've done, on other similar pages I've used the SelectorGadget (https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to identify nodes to scrape by entering into `library(rvest)` 's `html_text()` argument, but SelectorGadget seems not to work in either of these cases, so I'm a little clueless on another approach.

Any tips on how to scrape the very large font "Month Year" header in either or both of these pages? My intended output is getting the month and year of the table, ie `monyr <- "August 2019"` for the case of today's date.

http://cdec.water.ca.gov/cgi-progs/reports.cur?s=fnf

http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=FNF

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can extract the title of the table. After, just extract the month and year.

```
library(rvest)

read_html('http://cdec.water.ca.gov/cgi-progs/reports.cur?s=fnf') %>%
  html_nodes("h1") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: great! how did you know to use `h1`?

Comment: right click on the page and inspect the html code. I found this `<h1>Daily Full Natural Flows for August 2019</center></h1>`